# Derivative of $\frac{x^py^q}{x^2+y^2};\; p,q\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $$ f(x,y) =
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x^py^q}{x^2+y^2}&\quad \text{for } (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
0 &\quad \text{for } (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{array}\right..
$$
Find all $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ so that

1. $\partial f/ \partial x$ and $\partial f/ \partial y$ exist.
2. $\partial f/ \partial x$ and $\partial f/ \partial y$ are continuous.
3. $f$ is differentiable.

I've only been able to work out continuity.
On the path $(x,x)$, $f(x,x) = x^{p+q}/(2x^2)$. So for $f$ to be continuous, $p+q \ge 3$. If $p+q \ge 3$, $p$ or $q\ge 2$, so WLOG assume $q \ge 2$ and $p\ge 1$. Then

$$
|f(x,y)| = \left|\frac{x^py^q}{x^2+y^2}\right| \le \frac{|x^p||y^2||y^{q-2}|}{|y^2|} \to 0 \text{ as } (x,y) \to (0,0).
$$

The partial derivatives on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus (0,0)$ are
$$
\partial f/\partial x = \frac{(p-2)x^{p+1}y^q + px^{p-1}y^{q+2}}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
$$
\partial f/\partial y = \frac{(q-2)x^{p}y^{q+1} + qx^{p+2}y^{q-1}}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
My guess for continuity of the partials is $p+q\ge 4$ but I can't confirm it.

Please help! Is there a general strategy about investigating the derivatives of functions with parameters $p,q$ like this?

Thank you!

Comment: That denominator begs for a transformation with x=r cos $\theta$ and y = r sin $\theta$ so the denominator goes to $r^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$ Define \; g(r,\theta) = f(r\; cos\; \theta, r\;sin\;\theta) $$

$$ g(r,\theta) = r^{p+q-2}cos^p\theta sin^q\theta$$

So the only constraint on continuity is that p+q >= 3.  [EDIT]

(its 3 because partial derivative w.r.t. r has factor $r^{p+q-3}$).